# Conundrum with init() and dispatch_sync

Tags: initialization, swift, grand-central-dispatch

In a class, I have the following `init()` function:

```
init() {
    let q = 0
    dispatch_sync(queue) {
        self._state = State(q)
    }
}
```

where `_state` is an instance of a struct `State` and `queue` a global dispatch queue.

I'm using the `dispatch_sync` call in order to synchronize the potentially concurrently accessed instance of the class.

I'm running in some weird issue, that the compiler is complaining about using the `_state` variable before it´s being initialized (namely using it in the block, before it is being initialized):

```
main.swift:363:37: error: variable 'self._state' used before being initialized
    dispatch_sync(s_sync_queue) {
                                ^
```

However, the sole purpose of using the dispatch queue and the block is to initialize the ivar.

The compiler even states, the code would return without initializing the variable `_state`:

```
main.swift:372:5: error: property 'self._state' not initialized
}
^
```

albeit, clearly, due to `dispatch_sync` the function `init` cannot return without leaving the variable `_state` uninitialized.

So, how could I solve the issue in an efficient manner?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to declare _state as optional if you can.(If there is no harm to do that)

```
  var _state:State?
```

if you make this optional you can use it in `dispatch_sync`.

Comment: Struct `State` is already an enum. I will investigate this approach. The initializer requires a parameter. Perhaps, I could define a "default" initializer - with a special "NotInitialized" enum value.

Comment: Can you post more code??It will help to solve problem.

Comment: The idea is to provide an init function without a parameter: `init()` - which default initializes the struct. Then, it would be possible to use that variable in a block, where it is setup completely.